# Kivy: Why is the ViewClass refreshed and resized so often?

Tags: python, kivy, refresh, kivy-recycleview

I am trying to implement a custom reload mechanism, for this I need to know when a widget has to be refreshed. Unfortunately it seems that Kivy is calling multiple refreshes for one element at the beginning which is sometimes creating unexpected behavior for my custom reloading (uses same picture for two different ViewClasses).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory as F
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

kv = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'       
    MRecycleView:
        id:rv
        viewclass: 'MyViewClass'
        data: [{'why': "..."} for i in range(5)]     
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 3
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height  
            spacing: dp(20)

<MyViewClass>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    height:self.minimum_height
    index:-1
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height:20
        text:"asd"
"""

class MyViewClass(F.BoxLayout,F.RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):         
        self.index = index                   
        print("refresh_view_attrs",self.size,self.index)
    
    def on_size(self, *args) -> None:           
        print("on_size",self.size,self.index)
    

class MRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

MyApp().run()
```

The output is:

```
on_size [100, 0] -1
refresh_view_attrs [100, 0] 0
on_size [100, 0] 0
refresh_view_attrs [100, 0] 1
on_size [100, 0] 0
refresh_view_attrs [100, 0] 2
on_size [20.0, 0] 0
on_size [20.0, 0] 1
on_size [20.0, 0] 2
on_size [20.0, 20] 0
on_size [20.0, 20] 1
on_size [20.0, 20] 2
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 0
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 1
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 2
on_size [100, 0] 0
refresh_view_attrs [100, 0] 3
on_size [100, 0] 0
refresh_view_attrs [100, 0] 4
on_size [20.0, 0] 3
on_size [20.0, 0] 4
on_size [20.0, 20] 3
on_size [20.0, 20] 4
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 0
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 1
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 2
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 3
refresh_view_attrs [20.0, 20] 4
on_size [253.33333333333334, 20] 0
on_size [253.33333333333334, 20] 1
on_size [253.33333333333334, 20] 2
on_size [253.33333333333334, 20] 3
on_size [253.33333333333334, 20] 4
```

The data contains 5 elements but as you can see, some of them are initially refreshed 3 times (due to some mysterious kivy recycleview mechanisms). Basically I just need a consistent way to get the current ViewClasses after they are "ready" to be displayed, so after the final refresh was called. But how can I determine it? Are there any flags in the RV or any events for that?